# classification mnist binary class

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, mnist

I want to implement a Neural Network for MNIST dataset, and I find a lot of example on the net. But I want study this problem using a different approach: I want create 10 NNs (as the number of classes) in which I classify only a class with the rest of the others (example: first NN analyze only the "1" class vs the others).
It's just an exercise (I'm python newbie and I want to learn).

This is my actually python code, do you have any suggests to modify mi code in order to obtain the classes separation that I explained above?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
from keras.utils import np_utils
numpy.random.seed()


(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3])
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')

X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
print(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
def baseline_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels,           kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))        

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model


 model = baseline_model()

 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=3,     batch_size=200, verbose=2)

 model.summary()
 scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
 print("Baseline Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should transform `y_train` and `y_test` into binary outputs. You will want to do this in a loop for each of the ten classes, but here is how you would do it for one of those, say 5:

```
y_train_binary = (y_train == 5).astype(np.int)
y_test_binary = (y_test == 5).astype(np.int)
```

Right now each `y_train` example is a number from 1 to 10, so here we convert it to 0 or 1 corresponding to whether the positive class is correct.

Then you want to adjust the output of your model to support binary classification. This can be done by using a single dense output neuron with sigmoid activation and binary crossentropy loss:

```
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))   
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Imran! i dont't understand why I use 5...can you explain me? Furthermore, np.int was marked as "undefined", I must import any other library? Sorry for my bad question, I'm a newbie for Python

Comment: That was just an example - each entry in `y_train` is a number between `1` and `10`. In my example we convert `5` to `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`. You should wrap everything below `load_data()` in a loop, outputting a different model for each class.

Comment: Thanks, and for the np.int?

Comment: `(y_train == 5)` gives you an array of booleans, and `astype(np.int)` converts it to `1`s and `0`s.

Comment: Perfect I understand, but my editor mark np as undefined. Why? It's necessary import a library?

Comment: Sorry I did `import numpy as np` rather than `import numpy`. Either use my import or replace `np` with `numpy`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's work. Before I proceed i have another(last) question: i must replace my model.add(.....) code with yours or I simply add yours to mine?

Comment: That was meant to replace the last layer and the `model.compile` line you have.

Comment: Perfetc. Now I run this code and I have tis error
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10,), why? How can I fix?

Comment: I'm not able to run your code because the line `X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3])` gives an error. But are you using the transformed `y_train` and `y_test` everywhere?

Comment: No problem, this line is just in a comment. I change in your suggested code the y_train_binary in y_test_binary (you have repeat y_train two times). Then i replaced every where t_test binary and y_train binary.

Comment: Can you help me? why i have the Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (10,)